# Setting DataContext of elements inside XAML?

Tags: wpf

Hi am trying to get the hang of binding.

The XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="WPF_SandBox.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel">
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox_FirstName" Width="200" Margin="0,100,0,0" Text="{Binding Path=FirstName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  />
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox_LastName" Width="200" Margin="0,10,0,0" Text="{Binding Path=LastName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock_FullName"  Background="LightBlue" Width="200" Margin="0,10,0,0" Text="{Binding Path=FullName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

The C# code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Person person = new Person { FirstName = "Matt", LastName = "Smith" };
            stackPanel.DataContext = person;

        }
    }

    public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        string firstName;
        string lastName;

        public string FirstName
        {
            get
            { 
                return firstName;
            }
            set
            {
                firstName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
                OnPropertyChanged("FullName");
            }
        }

        public string LastName
        {
            get { return lastName; }
            set
            {
                lastName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("LastName");
                OnPropertyChanged("FullName");
            }
        }

        public string FullName
        {
            get
            {
                return String.Format("{0}, {1}",lastName,firstName);
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
            }
        }
    }
```

When started, a window with 2 textboxes and 1 textblock shows. Inside the window constructor, I have created an instance of person and assigned the DataContext of the stackPanel to this instance. The first textbox is binded to the FirstName property of the Person class, the second TextBox is binded to the LastName property and the final TextBlock just prints the LastName property followed by the FirstName properties. As I said earlier, I set the DataContext of the stackPanel inside the C# code. How can I set it instead inside the XAML? For example:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel" DataContext="person">
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox_FirstName" Width="200" Margin="0,100,0,0" Text="{Binding Path=FirstName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  />
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox_LastName" Width="200" Margin="0,10,0,0" Text="{Binding Path=LastName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock_FullName"  Background="LightBlue" Width="200" Margin="0,10,0,0" Text="{Binding Path=FullName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  />
    </StackPanel>
```

This doesn't work, but as you can see I am trying to set the DataContext of the stackPanel inside the XAML, how would I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: @NETscape Well am currently learning how to make windows 8 store apps, and WPF is a big part of that. Other then MVVM, is there anything else I should focus on?

Comment: Reading MVVM resources will teach you what you need to know, you are also always welcome to the [WPF chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18165/wpf).

Answer (score 5):

[**This brief article**](http://www.milosev.com/index.php/98-c/wpf/304-two-ways-of-setting-datacontext) explains the two ways of setting the DataContext: through XAML or through code. Here's the code:

```
public class HelloWorldDataContextModel
{
    public string HelloWorld { get; set; }

    public HelloWorldDataContextModel()
    {
        HelloWorld = "Hello world!";   
    }
}
```

And the XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="HelloWorldDataContext.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"       
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"        
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HelloWorldDataContext"        
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">    

    <Window.Resources>
        <local:HelloWorldDataContextModel x:Key="HelloWorldDataContext" />   
    </Window.Resources>    

    <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource HelloWorldDataContext}">        
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="222,127,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding HelloWorld}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>    
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Ah thanks, I have googled trying to find a decent article/website to explain this but just couldn't. So is this the recommended way/best way?

Comment: Can you explain what the line " xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HelloWorldDataContext" " does please? Also Text="{Binding HelloWorld}"binds to the property "HelloWorld" of the HelloWorldDataContextModel.cs file? What is a static resource? I have googled it but I cant find examples to help me understand the syntax/what it does...

Answer (score 1):

To add to Abbas's answer, when you have a parameterless constructor, which you might find happen more often when applying MVVM, you can also set the `DataContext` of a control a difference way.

```
<Window x:Class="HelloWorldDataContext.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"       
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"        
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HelloWorldDataContext"        
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">    

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:HelloWorldDataContextModel />   
    </Window.DataContext>    

    <Grid>        
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="222,127,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding HelloWorld}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>    
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

You will get the same result using mine or Abbas's method; however when parameter's are required by a constructor, it's not worth it to go about this way.

Comment: Can you explain what the line " xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HelloWorldDataContext" " does please? Also Text="{Binding HelloWorld}"binds to the property "HelloWorld" of the HelloWorldDataContextModel.cs file? But you haven't applied a DataContext to the Grid panel? Also could you explain what a static resource is, and how am meant to use it/the syntax or direct me to a good site explaining it, as I cant find one through google.

Comment: If you don't explicitly set the DataContext of an control (Grid/StackPanel/TextBox/etc), it will inherit the DataContext of it's Parent Control. IE...set the Windows DataContext and all controls within it will inherit that DataContext. There is a caveat that some controls are not a part of the Visual Tree and then won't inherit the DataContext, such as a ContextMenu.

Comment: The XAML code "xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HelloWorldDataContext" is importing the namespace HelloWorldDataContext like "using HelloWorldDataContext" in C# code. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514546(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why you trying to set DataContext of StackPanel though you can set DataContext of Window  and use it further, but still if you want to then try this

> xaml

```
 <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel" DataContext="{Binding Person}">
```

> xaml.cs

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        Person = new Person { FirstName = "Matt", LastName = "Smith" };
    }
    Person person;
    public Person Person
    {
        get { return person; }
        set { person = value; OnPropertyChanged("Person"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
}
```

Or instead of Setting DataContext of StackPanel use dataContext of Window and Bind textblock text like Person.FirstName .....

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox_FirstName" Width="200" Margin="0,100,0,0" Text="{Binding Path=Person.FirstName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  />
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox_LastName" Width="200" Margin="0,10,0,0" Text="{Binding Path=Person.LastName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock_FullName"  Background="LightBlue" Width="200" Margin="0,10,0,0" Text="{Binding Path=Person.FullName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  />
```